Avoid a re-render using SWR when data returned doesn't change even if the key changes?
On my Next.js I am fetching data from and endpoint using SWR. I am then displaying these records in a table which has some filters I can send as query params to the endpoint.
I am fetching a list of transactions using the following hook:
export const useTransactions = (
  identity?: string | null,
  pageIndex = 0,
  limit = 10,
  query = {}
) => {
  const {
    data,
    mutate: mutatePublicOwnerTransactions,
    ...response
  } = useOwnSWR<OwnerTransactionsResponse>(
    identity
      ? `/transactions?identity=${identity}&page=${pageIndex}&limit=${limit}&${new URLSearchParams(
          query
        ).toString()}`
      : null,
    { refreshInterval: 30000 }
  );
  return {
    historyRecords: data,
    mutatePublicOwnerTransactions,
    ...response,
  };
};

Among other params in the query prop I am passing two values for dates, a start date, and and end date.
I want to update the table where I am rendering the transactions when there's a new transaction so I have the {refreshInterval: 30000} to refetch every 30 seconds and update the table. Because as the end date I am sending the current timestamp every time I refetch, the key passed to  useOwnSWR changes and my table is re-rendering even when the data is the same.
My assumption was that the component wouldn't re-render as the data is the same and SWR performs a comparison of the current and the previous data to avoid a re-render, but that isn't happening in my case.
My workaround so far was to call the endpoint twice in the component, one with the URL query and one without and have one call for all the transactions and one call for the filtered transactions but I thought there has to be a better option. Is there something to avoid using the two endpoint calls workaround?
